# Can't delete remote master branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to delete the remote master branch:

```
git push origin :master
```

My list of branches:

```
$ git branch -avv
* survey-content                c3356d9 [origin/survey-content] Runtime textures for survey
  remotes/origin/master         4300c27 New Survey layout for message header
  remotes/origin/survey-content c3356d9 Runtime textures for survey
```

When I do the `git push` I mentioned earlier, I get the following error:

```
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To c:/Dropbox/Repositories/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'c:/Dropbox/Repositories/repo.git'
```

This is a bare repository that I'm pushing to, so there should be no "current branch". Why can't I delete the master branch remotely? It should be no different from any other branch, especially since I have previously gotten rid of `origin/HEAD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All* git repositories have a "current branch" unless they have a "detached HEAD".<sup>1</sup>

(If you remove the file `HEAD`, git no longer considers the repository to be a repository.  So there's always a `HEAD` and whatever `ref: refs/heads/branch` branch-name it contains is the current branch, even if it's a bare repo.)

As the error message says, to allow deletion you can set a git config variable.  I'm not sure what happens if you do delete that branch though (see footnote).

---

<sup>1</sup>Detaching HEAD in a bare repo will probably allow the deletion, but will cause a bit of weirdness when doing `git clone` from it.  There's a sort of bug in the git protocols: when you connect to a remote and ask it about its references, it can't show you any indirect references as indirect.  Since `HEAD` is almost always an indirect ref pointing to a branch, the git on the system on which you're doing the cloning—your local git, in other words—has a hack: it asks the remote git for a list of all its references and their SHA-1s, and then it looks to see which branch has the same SHA-1 as `HEAD`.  It then assumes that must be the branch that the remote is "on", and that's the default branch for the `git clone` to check-out.  Which works great unless there are either zero, or two or more, branches with that SHA-1....

Comment: IMHO bare repositories should enable that variable by default, it's more annoying than helpful to not have it set. Thanks for the explanation though, for a newbie like me it just seems unintuitive for it to behave so strangely.

Comment: There's a lot of weirdness in git... :-)

Answer (score 0):

That is because github is looking at the **master** branch to provide the web content when you browse that repository. So we first have to make github look at our placeholder branch instead, then delete master.

First push up the placeholder branch:

- git checkout **placeholder** *# if not on placeholder already*
- git push origin **placeholder**
  Then set **placeholder** to be the github default branch. Go to the main github page for your forked repository, and click on the “Admin” button.

There’s a “Default branch” dropdown list near the top of the screen. From there, select **placeholder**. On the interface I’m looking at, a green tick appears above the dropdown list. Now you can do (from the command line):

- git push origin :master

and - no master branch...